# What are the reasons for "Bad input error" in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, function, python-requests

i am getting this bad input error while running code in coursera auto grader, but when i run this code in python interpreter it runs fine

[image: an image screenshot of their autograder]

whats the problem kindly help me please!!

```
def computepay(h,r):
    if h>40:
        opay = h*r
        mpay = (h-40.0) * (r*0.5)
        p = opay+mpay
        return p
    else:
        p=h*r
        return p
hrs = input("Enter hrs")
rate = input("Enter rate")
fh,fr = float(hrs),float(rate)
print("pay:",computepay(fh,fr))
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the code as text instead of linking to screenshots.  https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001665.htm

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text. Python can't load image with code and run it - so we can't test it.

Comment: code seems OK. Maybe you have wrong indentations - maybe you mix spaces and tabs and it makes problem. You may try to rewrite all indentations using only spaces. And maybe next time use some text editor which automatically convert tabs to spaces.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put the return outside the if else statement

```
def computepay(h,r):
    if h>40:
        opay = h*r
        mpay = (h-40.0) * (r*0.5)
        p = opay+mpay
    else:
        p=h*r
    return p
hrs = input("Enter hrs")
rate = input("Enter rate")
fh,fr = float(hrs),float(rate)
print("pay:",computepay(fh,fr))
```